# Occasional failing of static:: and self:: methods on some servers in PHP

Tags: php, constants, static-methods

I noticed failing of static:: and self:: in static methods on some servers in PHP (PHP 5.3.23) but not on others (PHP 5.6+) The following code runs error-free on my local (XAMPP) server:

```
public static function display_admin_notice_after_redirect( $message_id ){
    add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', function( $url ) use ( $message_id ){
        return add_query_arg(
            array( self::MSG_QUERY_ARG => $message_id ),
            $url
        );
    } );
}
```

Whereas on my live site I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active
```

Is there something going on with PHP versions and how they handle constants?

Why should this work on one server and not on another?

Comment: So what version are you running locally? and what version on your live site? [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) was introduced in PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Both are post PHP 5.3, though I don't know exact versions (I will verify). Having said that, both static:: and self:: are failing with the same error, so maybe it's not a late static binding issue.

Comment: I'd love it if people left their reasons for a downvote on a question.

Comment: An update to PHP 5.6+ solved the error, but I'd still like to understand what the issue with self:: was from the context of a static class method.